# Length of the curve parameterized by $(x,y,z)=(a\cos t \sin t, a\sin t\sin t, ab\sin t)$, for $0\leq t\leq2\pi$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have a curve described by the following:

$$\begin{align}
x &= a\cos(t)\sin(t)\\  
y &= a\sin(t)\sin(t)\\
z &= ab\sin(t)
\end{align}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are known, and $t$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$.

I'd like to know the pathlength of the curve, but the integral
$$\int \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 +\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+ \left(\dfrac{dz}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt$$ is beyond my ability to calculate.

Is there a simpler way to determine the pathlength of this curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by noting that:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac a2 \sin 2t\right) = a \cos 2t, \quad \frac{dy}{dt} = a \sin 2t
$$

So,
$$
\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dt}\right)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + a^2 b^2 \cos^2 t}=|a| \sqrt{1+b^2 \cos^2 t}
$$

Can you compute the integral now?

Comment: last term under the square root should be $dz/dt$

Comment: @enzotib thanks, copy/paste...

Comment: not a simple integral, anyway

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed that I missed an identity. I can handle it from here though, thanks!

Comment: @enzotib Yes, not a simple integral... Wolfram mathematica uses elliptic integrals computing the primitive function. Must confess I did not try to solve it.\